# Is there a default parameter choice for the spike-and-slab prior?

Tags: regression, bayesian, model-selection

In the [spike-and-slab prior](https://stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall05/sta395/joelucas1.pdf), one needs to specify $h_{0j} = P(\beta_j=0)$, which demonstrates our prior belief about how likely $\beta_j$ to be an important predictor.

Is there a default choice for this $h_{0j}$? Perhaps one that leads to a prior uniform distribution over the entire model space?

Comment: This parameter is a prior probability of the null and hence $1\big/2$ can be construed as a default choice. I do not understand how this relates with a uniform prior over the entire "model space", unless you mean a prior over $\{0,1\}$, in which case it is true, if trivial.

Comment: Let's say we have two potential predictors $(X_1, X_2)$, then the entire model space is $(None, X_1, X_2, X_1 + X_2)$. Is there a prior that put a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$ on each element of that model space?

Comment: Yes, 1/2 for all j will be uniform over all models. But notice it is not uniform over model size. In your two predictor example, it is twice as likely the model will have 1 predictor than it is the model will have none (or two).

Answer (score 1):

This is actually described in the paper you quote:

[image]

So it is an locally [uniform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) distribution that defines the same probability of all the values with a "spike" (i.e. larger probability) for some value. Let me change the notation for a moment, say we have spike-and-slab distribution so that $x \in [-\alpha, \alpha]$ with a spike at point $\beta$. If the distribution was uniform then probability (density)  of some $x \in [-\alpha, \alpha]$ would be $\frac{1}{2\alpha}$. Knowing that you can choose some value for your parameter ($\gamma \in [0, 1)$) that reflects *your prior assumptions* about the model, i.e. how much more probable you would like the $x=\beta$ value to be comparing to the other values. Then your pdf becomes:

$$
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{1-\gamma}{2\alpha} & \mathrm{for}\ -\alpha \le x \le \alpha\ \mathrm{and}\ x \neq \beta, \\
  \gamma & \mathrm{for}\ x = \beta, \\
  0 & \mathrm{for}\ x<-\alpha\ \mathrm{or}\ x>\alpha.
  \end{cases} 
$$

In this case the bigger $\gamma$ is, the smaller is probability of other values, so choosing different values will make $x=\beta$ more or less probable comparing to other values. It is your *subjective* choice to decide how much more probable you want this value to be.

In general, there is no such a thing as "default priors". Priors are always problem-specific and reflect your prior assumptions. You can use "uniform everywhere" approach but this also reflects your assumptions about uniform distribution of your parameters.

Comment: I may be wrong, but my understanding of the screenshot is that it's talking about the slab part of the prior, which is indeed diffuse and uniform over the two limit $-f_j$ and $f_j$. However, what I'm asking about is the prior probability of the spike part, i.e. the probability that $\beta$ lands in the "bit of probability mass concentrated at 0". I don't think the authors specify a "default" / "safe to try" prior for that probability (which is $h_{0j}$, not $\sigma$).